# Count of unique prime number

Tags: java, arrays

Im trying to take count of the unique prime numbers,im able to print the unique prime number but unable to take count , also im not suppose to use an extra array ?
my logic after finding the prime number went wrong ! can anyone help me with this ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);   
        System.out.println("Please enter your array limit");    
        int limit=sc.nextInt();    
        int array[]=new int[limit];    
        System.out.println("please enter your array elements ");    
        for(int i=0;i<limit;i++) {     
            array[i]=sc.nextInt();     
        }     
        int flag=0;   
        for(int i=0;i<limit;i++) {     
            int counter=0;      
            for (int j=1;j<=array[i];j++) {      
                if(array[i]%j==0) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            if(counter==2) {
                System.out.println(array[i]);
                for(int k=i;k<limit;k++) {
                if(array[i]!=array[k]) {
                    flag++;
                }
                }
                }
        }
System.out.println("Count of unique prime number: "+flag);
sc.close();
}
}

output:
Please enter your array limit
6
please enter your array elements 
1 2 3 4 5 6
2
3
5
Count of unique prime number: 8
//expected output 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: if you need only unique values, you might want to insert them into a Set and in the end return the size of the Set, like this:

```
int flag = 0;
Set<Integer> primeNumbers = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
  int counter = 0;
  for (int j = 1; j <= array[i]; j++) {
    if (array[i] % j == 0) {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  if (counter == 2) {
    primeNumbers.add(array[i]);
    System.out.println(array[i]);
  }
}
```

In the end just return `primeNumbers.size()`. This works because a Set data-structure does not allow duplicate values.

There is no need to do a second loop after encountering a prime number (i.e counter == 2). Just change the code after that if condition with:

```
if (counter == 2) {
  System.out.println(array[i]);
  flag++;
}
```

In the end just print/return the flag. Happy coding! =)

Comment: thanky you, i really appreciate help. I have already tried the above steps but if have repeaing prime numbers in the array then the flag will count that as well, i just need unique prime number count. and yes your suggestion works if there is no any repeating elements in the array . Thank you

Comment: I just updated the answer!

Comment: Hey @MuhammedShameel did my answer help you solve your problem? If so I would really appreciate it if you chose it as correct!

Comment: Yes thank you, appreciate your help brother!